# Prevent click event on any element if a pan (mousedown + mousemove + mouseup) occurred

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-events, pan, mouseup

I have a page with many elements with a callback bound to the **click event** on each one.

The page is bigger than the viewport and the user may scroll the standard way (using the mouse-wheel, scroll bars...)

Now I need to implement a **pan mode**, giving the user another way to scroll the page:

The user clicks, drags with mouse-down and the page scrolls.

I implemented this easily registering mousedown, mousemove and mouseup on the body element. As the user drags I scroll the window with **window.scrollTo()**

**The problem:** as the page moves under the mouse pointer, if the user pan the page clicking on an element then the mousedown and the mouseup occurr on that same element and this triggers a **click event** too on that element after the mouseup.

This off course is unwanted.

The click event is on a child element (mouse dowm-move-up are on body) so **stopPropagation** doesn't help.

**Question:** at the end of the mouseup callback, when actually a drag occurred (I can check this comparing initial and final mouse coordinates), can I prevent the click event to trigger?

Comment: just a comment:set a globel variable and check it on click event. and change it when drag. this was my first idea

Comment: yes, this is what I'll do if I don't find a more elegant and simpler solution. I don't like to have every callback for the click event to check the global.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily by simply canceling the click event in the capture phase of the body:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", allowClick, true);
function allowClick(event) {
    if (panMode) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZCkM/) for an example of ignoring a click based on a global flag.  (Tested in the latest Firefox, Chrome and IEs.)

See [javascript.info](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) for a clear description of the capture and bubble phases of events in Javascript.

Comment: Works very well. Unfortunately I want to support for some more time IE8 and addEventListener is not supported. So I have to check "panMode" on every click callback... that's what I was trying to avoid but seems to be no other way.